# I need to register and resize images, safe to delete plugin afterwards?

Tags: plugins, images

I need to register a new particular size of image for my site, something I can do like this:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180 );
```

However, I will need to resize previous images. I can use a plugin like "Regenerate Thumbnails" but my question is, is it safe to delete that plugin after use? Probably the answer is yes but just want to be 100% sure. Thanks

Comment: That's a question you should ask to the plugin author, but I'm pretty sure it is safe.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ I guess the action would have taken place using the plugin so its purpose afterward is redundant

Comment: I might be wrong, though, and I was just referring to the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin. For other plugins, you'll just have to test on your own - e.g. try on a test site and see if deleting the plugin causes any issues. But logically, the plugin should ensure things will continue to work normally after the plugin is deleted or deactivated.